# Other old vampires in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls, skyrim

In the expansion of Skyrim, Dawnguard, one has to escort Serana to her family's castle. Upon arrival, her father Harkon says that his covenant is one of the oldest vampire covenants in Skyrim.

Does anyone know if there are other truly old vampires in Skyrim?

I'm not counting the mother of Serana, since she was originally from the same covenant.

Comment: There could be others added by mods so you need to say if mods are excluded

Comment: Mods are excluded.

Answer (score 4):

We don't know about Skyrim, but in Morrowind there were at least three other covenants:

- The Berne Clan is a vampire clan led by Raxle Berne based in the Dwemer ruins of Galom Daeus (near a lava lake west of Tel Uvirith, west-northwest of the Erabenimsun Camp). These vampires are the true masters of the night. Sliding through the darkness, invisible in the shadows, they hunt their prey in secrecy and silence.
- The Aundae Clan, a vampire clan led by Dhaunayne Aundae, can be found in the Ashmelech tomb (on the medium sized island far southwest of Dagon Fel). They are a dark brotherhood of vampiric mages "blessed" with dark powers of the mind; their path through the darkness relies on their mastery of magic.
- The Quarra Clan is a vampire clan led by Volrina Quarra and can be found in the Dwemer ruins of Druscashti (east of Khuul). They fear nothing, and with good reason. Of all the clans, they are the strongest...at least physically. They are not subtle, and would rather slaughter an entire village than choose a few on which to feed.

All the leaders of those covenants are considered "old"